# Can you please help me on installing Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi

I have tried several times on installing Ubuntu.But I cant able to install it. My laptop is ASUS TUF fx505ge gaming series. It have SSD 256 and 1 tb HDD and NVDIA GPU. I have installed Ubuntu, but I have a problem and it's because of my graphics card. I have tried "nouvemodeset" commands to resolve it. But on The next Install I have chosen mirror install during the installation, but due to a networking issue the installation failed. After that incident I couldn't  install Ubuntu. Every time during my installation I followed these steps.

1. Boot Ubuntu from flash drive in UEFI mode.
2. Changed to AHCI in BIOS (to install it on an SSD).
3. Disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot.

During boot I have chosen the live option and gone to live mode. In live mode I have tried to install it. But every time after reaching GRUB the installation it fails to install. I have tried several times, but it's no use. I always had the same issue, so I have tried different Ubuntu versions, Linux Mint, etc. Everything has same issue during installation.
The GRUB installation fails and the installation gets aborted. I have   also tried CSM mode, but still the issue can't be resolved.

Comment: You've got either everything wrong or one small thing wrong depending on how you play it. Minimally all that's wrong is that the Ubuntu installer can't install GRUB unless you get happy about multiplying your problems from there. You don't need to install GRUB however. Install Ubuntu without GRUB, then boot from a live Boot-Repair USB flash drive and select the Recommended repair. Boot from the Ubuntu live USB again and reinstall Ubuntu. This time the Ubuntu installer will find the 500MB EFI System Partition that Boot-Repair created and install Ubuntu all the way to the end, including  GRUB.

Comment: how do  I install Ubuntu with out installing GRUB. always grub issue occurs and installation got failed bro

Comment: The Ubuntu installer installs everything except for grub and after that installing grub is the last thing it does, so install everything but grub and then reboot from the Boot-Repair live USB and select the *Recommended repair* option to install grub using Boot-Repair. Ubuntu probably won't boot from this hybrid grub, but if you reinstall Ubuntu it will overwrite everything with a complete working Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

see if there is grub installation on your EFI drive. if there is remove it first before installation of ubuntu. [refer this link for removal of grub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxYSzxXawjU)

Comment: I have formated my whole SSD and HDD before installation. and there is nothing left there. So what would I do?

Answer (score 0):

so i think there is problem with the app with which you make a bootable drive. it happened with me once because i always use **Rufus** but that time i had to use **Belena etcher** instead. so try with different apps, see if it works.

Comment: let me try it bro.. Thanks for your help